# render animated QGraphicsSvgItem(s) on QGraphicsScene with QSvgRenderer

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, svg

### What I do:

I am creating a new QGraphicsScene:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene;
```

I have a class inherited from QGraphicsSvgItem:

```
//hFile
class MySVGItem: public QGraphicsSvgItem
{
public:
    MySVGItem(QSvgRenderer *renderer, int x, int y);

    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    QPainterPath shape() const;

private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

---

```
//cpp File
Roboter::Roboter(QSvgRenderer *renderer, int x, int y)
{
    this->setSharedRenderer(renderer);
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    setZValue((x + y) % 2);
}
```

---

I fill my scene with some of these Items and they all share the same renderer, cause they should display the same svg.

```
QSvgRenderer *renderer = new QSvgRenderer(QLatin1String(":/res/file.svg"));

//some <for> loops
QGraphicsSvgItem *item = new MySVGItem(renderer , x, y);
scene->addItem(item);
```

---

Then I set the scene to some QGraphicsView

```
view()->setScene(scene);
```

---

### What happens:

The Objects from MySVGItem are shown where they should be shown, but they are not animated correctly, like thy are standing still (until I activate some events, like hovering or dragging them - those code snippets not showed here).

---

### The actual question:

**How can I render those "MySVGItem" items correctly, showing their animation?**

### Edit

```
public
QRectF boundingRect() const;
QPainterPath shape() const;
```

---

```
QRectF MySVGItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200);
}

QPainterPath MySVGItem::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    return path;
}

//The svg File is 200x200
```

Comment: Incorrect `boundingRect` implementation can cause the problem. Please show `MySVGItem::boundingRect` and `MySVGItem::shape`.

Comment: I've added the Shape and BoundingRect Code I use as an EDIT in the previous post. Does that help?

Comment: No, it seems to be correct.

Comment: Do I need a timer to update() my svg, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You mast connect signal *QSvgRenderer::repaintNeeded()* to MySVGItem proxy slot, for example, "repaint".

Implementation of proxy slot

```
void MySVGItem::repaint()
{
  update();
}
```

OR

Use *QGraphicsSvgItem::renderer()* to have default "engine".